# how to introduce delay within the for loop in c# for windows web store app

Tags: c#, windows, textbox, delay

I am building a windows store app ,I am updating a text box value form  0 to 9 on a button click. Now, for updating I am using a for loop ,I want delay to be introduced within the for loop so that the user can see the changing values in the text box ,I tried  `Thread.Sleep(1000);`

here is my code for for loop

```
for(int n = 0; n < 10; n++)
{
    string rotate = Convert.ToString(n);
    for(int number = 0; number < 10; number++)
    {
        run[number].Text = rotate;
        //delay should be here;
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of loop use timer.

Comment: can you post any sample code

Answer (score 2):

please add this statment to add delay without UI hangging. aysnc call for delay.

```
await Task.Delay(1000);
```

Comment: not working ,getting an error  The name 'Task' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

To answer you question:

Instead of

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

you could use

```
Task.Delay(1000).Wait();
```

Of course, if you invoke it from the main thread, it will block your UI, but maybe that's your intention.